# VBA Excel Macro inserting heading before every row in excel table where there are merged rows

Tags: excel-formula

I'm new to excel macro programming. Help is sought from expertise here. 
[image: Snapshot from excel worksheet]

I need to enter the header (Item, Information direction (please see snapshot)) after every Serial Number (i.e 1, 2 (please see snapshot)). I have coded as below,but it does not work for the merged cells in excel as shown in snapshot.

I want to do this in a workbook containing over 50 worksheets, where each worksheet has such tables as seen in snapshot. It might be simple thing, but I am new to VBA macro. Thanks in advance for your solution, comments and time.

Code:

```
Sub WorksheetLoopmacro()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

               Cells.Find(What:="Item").Activate

            Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = ""

                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Copy
                ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
                Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Loop

        ' MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select

    Next I
```

End Sub

Comment: You may find the [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) and `Range.Rows.Count` properties useful here.

Comment: I have below code, but don't know how I can make use of below code in main code. Suggest please. Code: 
Sub CountMergedRows_2()
    For I = 1 To 100
        RowCount = Range("B" & I).MergeArea.Rows.Count
        If RowCount > 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Cell [B" & I & "] has " & RowCount & " merged rows")
            I = I + RowCount - 1 'note -1 here
        End If
    Next I
End Sub